# Latest version of Android client is buggy

Tags: bug, android-app

The latest version of the SE client is buggy on Android. Frequent screen garbage and random crashes. I'm not the only person with this problem, there are other comments in the Google Play store attesting to this.

For my system:

```
SE Android Client Version: 1.0.68
Nexus 7 Android Version: 5.1.1
```

[image: Screen capture of buggy screen]

Comment: Known issue with Tablets (at least Nexus), dev is aware of that and working on a fix.